# Best way to exclude a Meteor value from the database?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

What is the best way to exclude a field value from the data in Meteor when using Autoform, SimpleSchema, Collection2, etc? Say I have:

```
MySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  password: {
    type: String,
    label: "Enter a password",
    min: 8
  },
  confirmPassword: {
    type: String,
    label: "Enter the password again",
    min: 8,
    custom: function () {
      if (this.value !== this.field('password').value) {
        return "passwordMismatch";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

... and I do not want to confirmPassword field persisted to the database, what is the best way to handle that? I assume using hooks, but if so where and how? Hopefully there is a way to just exclude one (or more) values without having to redefine the whole whole schema to say which to include and which to exclude. If I have 100 fields and want to exlcude 1, hopefullly the hook or whatever does not need the other 99 defiled too.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With autoform, you must use a method on the server side. Simply delete the field in the method code when you receive it at the server before inserting the document.

Comment: So thing like myMehtod(doc)... doc.delete(extrastuff)...collection.insert(doc)? Will give that a shot and mark answered if it works - thanks!